# How can I have empty columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I need my query to return empty columns, so I can join it vertically with other queries that have more columns. This works:

> =QUERY({1\2\3};"select Col1, '-', Col3 LABEL '-' ''")

but how can I have multiple '-' columns?

BTW, is there a way to have QUERY output a NULL value instead of '-' (or empty cell, so it can be handled by ARRAYFORMULA)?

Comment: You can just use `Select Col1,1,2,3,`....

Comment: I want to have multiple columns containing the same "spacer" value (for example "-" or 0).

Comment: As you might've tried, That won't be possible. May be try spaces. `=QUERY(,"select ' ','  ','   '")` and then trim it off. `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY()))`

Comment: It turns out I need to aggregate (sum) the column, so I need a numeric here. So I ended up using 0, 0.000001, 0.00001, 0.0001 ... as column values, and I'll try flooring them. Too bad there is not a more elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Nice. Multiple Spaces can also be converted to zeroes. `=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(QUERY(,"select ' ','  ','   '"))*1)` i'm not sure it's rendering properly, but the first is 1 space, the second has 2 spaces and the third 3 space and so on